# How to accept Gradle Build Scan ToS automatically in a Maven project?

Tags: maven, gradle, build

I add the [Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/#maven) in my Maven project. How can I configure the Maven extension of the build scan to accept the Gradle Terms of Service automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the Maven build scan to the project, include the following `extensions.xml` file inside a directory called `.mvn` at the root of the Maven project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>com.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-enterprise-maven-extension</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.1</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Also add a file `gradle-enterprise.xml` inside the `.mvn` directory as follows:

```xml
<gradleEnterprise>
  <buildScan>
    <publish>ALWAYS</publish>
    <termsOfService>
      <url>https://gradle.com/terms-of-service</url>
      <accept>true</accept>
    </termsOfService>
  </buildScan>
</gradleEnterprise>
```

Then, you can run the build and the Gradle ToS will be accepted automatically.
See the [Gradle Enterprise Maven Extension User Manual](https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/maven-extension/#build_scans_captured_information) for more details and configuratio parameters.